# Interceptor is not triggered from another EJB method in same EJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, interceptor

### **Scenario**

2x same Interceptor in same EJB on 2 methods:

```
...
 @Interceptors(PerformanceAuditor.class)
public Date refreshIfNecessary() {
    // there is also the PerformanceAuditor-Interceptor on this method
    Pair<Date,String> lastImportDate = importDbDAO.findLatestImportLog();

    someContainer.reloadIfNecessary(lastImportDate);
    return lastImportDate.getLeft();
}

@Interceptors(PerformanceAuditor.class)
public boolean checkAndRefreshIfNecessary(final Date importDate) {
    Date lastImportDate = refreshIfNecessary();
    return lastImportDate.after(importDate);
}
...
```

Now we call on this EJB the methods externally with the following outcome:

- calling *refreshIfNecessary()* -> PerformanceAuditor is called **2 times**
- calling *checkAndRefreshIfNecessary()* -> PerformanceAuditor is called also **2 times**!
  (but **expected 3 times** since one nesting level more!)

So what's happening here?

Answer (score 10):

The answer is simple:

Interceptors "trigger" only if called as an "EJB call" (i.e. via their EJB interface). But in *checkAndRefreshIfNecessary()* the call of *checkAndRefreshIfNecessary()* is a simple Java method call and therefor not noticed by the container.

**Solution:** To call a method in an EJB internally as EJB call you have to go via its Interface which can be accessed e.g. via injected SessionContext and then via
*context.getEJBLocalObject()*... But this is certainly no a pretty solution! Better rethink your design in such cases!

**PS:** That's a beautiful example that one has still to understand the internals of an application server. Unfortunately from EJB3 onwards most features are so easy to use that more and more developers will not be confronted with the internals which will lead more often to such errors or at least bad design...

Comment: You are right. That's named proxification, this logic is also applied for transaction management for example. Another prettier sollution is to make responsability of your first EJB more simple (1 service = 1 responsability). So if you export your second method into another EJB, your interception will work and your application would be more readable / maintenable.